# Is there a way to not have Intellisense default to "on" in a new query window in SSMS?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, intellisense, ssms

I'm using SSMS (v10.50.2500.0) against a SQL Server 2008 R2 database.  I have [SQL Prompt](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-prompt/) installed and am tired of getting incorrectly red-lined by the built-in SSMS Intellisense whenever I open a new query window and start writing queries.  Is there an option in SSMS where I can default the native Intellisense to off when a new query window is opened?  I can't find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Menu system:

Tools -> Options

Then drill down to:

Text Editor -> Transact-SQL -> Intellisense

There you'll see the check box to "Enable Intellisense"

[image]